# why it's printing intialized value after assigning new value to that property?

Tags: ios, swift, closures

I am new to swift.Why the value of a is printed zero here?

```
var a = 0

var b = 0

let closure = { [a] in

   print(a,b)

}

a = 10

b = 10

closure()
```

Comment: Because you told the closure to *capture* `[a]`, this means it keeps the value above its declaration.